# Integral of partial derivative

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given that 
$$\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x_1}$$
How can I simplify the following?
$$\int_0^{x_2}\frac{\partial g_2(x_1,y)}{\partial x_1}\,\mathrm dy.$$

Note: If I just rewrite it as $$\int_0^{x_2}\frac{\partial g_1(x_1,y)}{\partial x_2} \,\mathrm dy.$$
Doesn't it become zero? Because seems like $\frac{\partial g_1(x_1,y)}{\partial x_2}$ should be zero, as $g_1$ is not a function of $x_2$.

If it is not zero, then can I write 
$$\int_0^{x_2}\frac{\partial g_1(x_1,y)}{\partial x_2} \,\mathrm dy = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\int_0^{x_2} g_1(x_1,y) \,\mathrm dy$$
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your omission of the arguments in the first line has led to great confusion. I believe the first line should read
$$\frac{\partial g_1(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial g_2(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1}.$$

So we have
$$\int_0^{x_2}\frac{\partial g_2(x_1,y)}{\partial x_1}\,dy
= \int_0^{x_2}\frac{\partial g_1(x_1,y)}{\partial y}\,dy= \dots$$
I left the problem for you to finish.

Comment: Thanks :) That first equation indeed confused me.